# работа с TimedRotatingFileHandler: как настроить его так, чтобы каждый раз файлы с датой на конце помещались в отдельную от path файла папку

Tags: python, логирование, python-2.7

Настроил данный `handler` следующим образом:

```
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(path,
                                                    when='D',
                                                    interval=7,
                                                    backupCount=4)
```

В итоге у меня получился файл `path`, который каждые 7 дней пишет логи в файл с таким же названием, но с датой на конце. Отлично, так и должно быть.

Единственное, не могу понять как настроить его так, чтобы каждый раз файлы с датой на конце помещались в отдельную от `path` файла папку.

Comment: есть [namer, rotator атрибуты](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html) в 3.3+ Какая у вас версия Питон?

Comment: @jfs версия 2.7